# Prefill form fields as values in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

> TL;DR Is it *possible* to prefill from one model in the same form builder to another model? Is there a correct way of solving this problem?

I have a form that takes several methods that requires to be passed in: `name`, `email`, `bio`, `location`, `homepage`, `work`.

Email method will need to be retrieved via Devise user model.

In my `new.html.erb`, it works fine as normal but it returns `nil` from the `email` field whenever I do the following:

```
<%= form_for :profile, url: profiles_path do |f| %>
  ...
  <div><% if current_user.email.present? %><%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.email_field current_user.email %><% end %></div>
<% end %>
```

`ProfilesController.rb`:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
    before_action :find_profile_by_id, only: [:show, :edit, :update]
    after_filter :destroy_user!, only: [:destroy]

def index
    if @profile.blank?
        render :new
    else
        render :show
    end
end

def new
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build
    @user = current_user.where('email=?')
end

def create
    @profile = current_user.profiles.build(profile_params)

    if @profile.save
        redirect_to @profile
    else
        render :new
    end
end

def show
end

def edit
end

def update
    if @profile.update(profile_params)
        redirect_to @profile
    else
        render :edit
    end
end

def destroy
    @user.destroy
    @profile.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
end

private

def profile_params
    params.require(:profile).permit(:name, :email, :bio, :location, :homepage, :work)
end

def find_profile_by_id
    @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy_user!
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
end
```

Is this the correct solution for this?

Comment: I suggest you edit your title to relate closer to your TLDR.

Comment: Title fixed. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems generally okay but try changing

```
<%= f.email_field current_user.email %>
```

To

```
<%= f.email_field(current_user, current_user.email) %>
```

Comment: I am getting `undefined method of merge, "john@example.com":string` error.

Comment: You should explain why this is better.